# Eclipse RCP - Pure e4 applications

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4, eclipse-luna

I literally cannot find any hands-on examples of pure e4 RCP applications. We're migrating a 3.x app to e4, but we do not know all the ups and downs.

I'm hoping for some guidance from the StackOverflow RCP gurus [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) & [Baz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449199/baz). :-)

Though I haven't found a similar question anywhere, if this is too broad or opinion-based, I shall remove it immediately.

Comment: I don't know of any examples, but I would start with [Lars Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) which goes through creating an app - he also has a book which is an extended version of the tutorial. Migrating a 3.x app can be hard work.

Comment: @greg-449 Followed the tutorial, and bought the actual book (latest   version). Tutorials and books are fine to some extent, but examples are nicer. Is anyone actually using e4?

Comment: There is a steady trickle of questions on SO and on the Eclipse e4 forum so I suppose some people are using e4. I have a substantial e4 app using more that 60 plugins.